# Postgres Multiple Joins

Tags: postgresql, join, left-join, jsonb

Not an expert on SQL but I managed to get this query working and delivering the results I need. The trick is to get it performing. The two tables in question will both have circa 6 mil records in them. Its currently running at around 3 mins, which is way of where I need it to be.

```
SELECT p.id,
       match.weight
FROM store_promotions p
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT id,
             (facets.weight::int * 1.5) AS weight
      FROM store_promotions promos
      JOIN -- this will return all promos, but add weight of 1.5 to the ones that are better matched to customer

        (SELECT (jsonb_array_elements(product) ->> 'key') AS barcode,
                (jsonb_array_elements(product) ->> 'doc_count') AS weight
         FROM customer_transaction_facets
         WHERE account_id = '1234567890') facets ON promos.products @> to_jsonb(facets.barcode::text)
      UNION SELECT id,
                   (facets.weight::int * .75) AS weight -- this will return all promos, but add weight of .75 for department matches to the ones that are better matched to customer
      FROM store_promotions promos
      JOIN
        (SELECT (jsonb_array_elements(department) ->> 'key') AS department,
                (jsonb_array_elements(department) ->> 'doc_count') AS weight
         FROM customer_transaction_facets
         WHERE account_id = '1234567890') facets ON promos.departments @> to_jsonb(facets.department::text)) matches) AS MATCH ON p.id = match.id WHERE storeid = '637'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, weight
from 
    store_promotions promos
    left join (
        select 
            (jsonb_array_elements(product) ->> 'key') as key,
            (jsonb_array_elements(product) ->> 'doc_count')::int * 1.5 as weight
        from customer_transaction_facets
        where account_id = '1234567890'
        union
        select 
            (jsonb_array_elements(department) ->> 'key') as key,
            (jsonb_array_elements(department) ->> 'doc_count')::int * 0.75 as weight
        from customer_transaction_facets
        where account_id = '1234567890'
    ) facets on 
        promos.products @> to_jsonb(facets.key::text)
        or
        promos.departments @> to_jsonb(facets.key::text)
where storeid = '637'
```